# Add new line while concatenating variable string

Tags: jquery, html, css

In an array variable, I am concatenating 2 variables and then storing it in an array .I want to add a linebreak between two variables. I tried `\n` and it is not working .

```
 var arrBackImg = new Array();
 var  frontText = new Array();
 for(......){
     frontText[i] = title+"\n"+description;
     backText[i]=title+":"+longdesc;
  }
```

how to add new line character in this variable???

Comment: `"\n"` is a newline character, but are you then trying to display the value in an html element? If so you'll need to use `<br>` to insert a line break element rather than `\n`.

Comment: System.Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try like

```
frontText[i] = title+"<br>"+description;
```

**BUT** **you should put that value as html like**

```
$('#txt').html(frontText[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<br>`

```
frontText[i] = title+"<br>"+description;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<br>`

```
  var arrBackImg = new Array();
  var  frontText = new Array();
    for(......) {
      frontText[i] = title+"<br>"+description;
      backText[i]=title+":"+longdesc;
    }
```

`<br>` is the tag used for *line breaks* in **HTML**